# Nonce shorthand in dictionary causing script1003 error on Explorer

Tags: javascript, dictionary, nonce

I'm using a nonce with AWS cognito to preserve state.  I followed an example from a Medium [article](https://medium.com/collaborne-engineering/preserve-deeplinks-during-cognito-login-flow-2c8f45731b52)

```
const nonce = auth.generateRandomString(auth.getCognitoConstants().STATELENGTH, auth.getCognitoConstants().STATEORIGINSTRING);
const state = {
    deepLink: window.location.href,
    nonce
};
console.log(state);
```

It looks like 'nonce' can be used as shorthand for a key-value pair, as the console log shows below, although I don't fully understand the shorthand part.

```
> deepLink:"https://example.com/mydeeplinkedpage.html"
> nonce: "iva3EtWzAZ92URHi9uXM6oqIEaagGOPO"
```

This is causing a "*script1003: expected ':'* " error in Explorer, I guess because it is expecting a colon to follow the key 'nonce' in the 'state' dictionary.

Is there a long-hand for including nonce in a dictionary, so that Explorer doesn't explode?  Is 'nonce' the only thing that can be used short-hand in a dictionary like this?

Comment: in modern browsers, if you have a variable called `fred` and you want to create an object with a key = "fred" with the value being what is in "fred", then there's a shorthand `{fred}` ... the word `nonce` is not special in this regard - but, note .. *modern* browsers, and IE is anything but modern ... it will also choke on `const` I would think (edit: nope, IE11 doesn't mind `const`, though the variable is anything but "const")

Comment: thanks @Bravo for the explanation, I didn't know about the shorthand

Comment: someone left a comment briefly that the long-hand way is to use nonce:nonce, but for some reason i can't see the comment any more.  if you want to add as an answer i can select it as the correct one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone else left an answer briefly and it's no longer there for some reason, so I can't attribute this answer to them.  The longhand way equivalent is as follows, and doesn't blow up in IE:

```
const state = {
    deepLink: window.location.href,
    nonce: nonce
};
```

Per @Bravo in the comments, the shorthand of just nonce is not specific to nonce.